# Random mp3 play with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let fileLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(self.navigationItem.title, ofType: "mp3", inDirectory: "Story")!

    try! player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL (string: fileLocation as String)!)

    player.play()
```

I have a folder with 4 MP3s, and a cell list accessing each one of those 4 MP3s.
Why is it playing the same MP3 again and again for each of those cells?

It is not even the first one from that folder, it is the last one!

[image: Cell list, Folder with the mp3!]

Answer (score 0):

Because your navigation item title is a constant value I guess.

Comment: If i change it i get the folowing error: ERROR77: timed out after 0.012s (159 160); mMajorChangePending=0

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a UITableView? If so, try doing it through the didselectviewatindexPath from UITableViewDelegate. Find the indexPath that is clicked and use that to play the mp3 for each cell.

Comment: This is the fuction. I don't know what your ideea is !                                                        `code`    func tableView  (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = songs [indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }